# For Loop in VueJS with TypeScript in object Array

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to do for loop in an object array.
This is my code

```
 private async rightsOverview() {
      let item: any[] = [];

      const prod = await fetchFromApi<ProductionBaseType>(`/productions/${id}/right-contracts`)
      const rightOverviewuser = await Promise.all(prod.map(async right => {
      const rightData = await fetchFromApi<ProductionBaseType>(`/productions/${id}/right-contracts/${right.id}/rights`)

 item.push({
          id: right.id,
          rightData: rightData,
          prod: right
        });

        return item
 }))

      console.log(item)
      this.productions = rightOverviewuser
 }
```

I have two API calls in this function and combined values in one object, till here it is working fine. Now i have the issue how can print values on the front end.

I did the console how i can see the values are printing

Console:

```
    [{
        id: "",
        prod: {object},
        rightData: {object}
    }]
```

Then i tried to loop through like this but it's not returning the values how i need them.

```
    <right-overview-list-item
             v-for="production in productions"
             :key="production.id"
             :production="production"
    />

    <div class="overview-list-item">
         {{ production.prod.toCompanyType.name }}
    </div>
    <div class="overview-list-item">
         {{ production.rightData.endDate }}
    </div>
```

I hope you understand what i want. If question is unclear please feel free to ask i will try to explain as much as i can.

Comment: So do you have values in console for `prod` and `rightData`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no nested properties could be returned as null/undefined, your issue is with the for loop. The scope for `v-for` elements only exists on or within the element/component where it's defined, so each `production` in `productions` as shown here:

```
 <right-overview-list-item
             v-for="production in productions"
             :key="production.id"
             :production="production"
    />
```

will only exist on this `right-overview-list-item` component, and not the two `<div>` elements defined after. You need to change it to something like this:

```
<template v-for="production in productions">
    <right-overview-list-item :production="production"/>
    <div class="overview-list-item">
         {{ production.prod.toCompanyType.name }}
    </div>
    <div class="overview-list-item">
         {{ production.rightData.endDate }}
    </div>
</template>
```